# UISearchController background not matching UINavigationBar background in iOS 11

Tags: objective-c, ios11

I'm updating an older app to support iPhone X and when updating a searchable UITableViewController the background of the UISearchController doesn't change when placing it in the navigation bar.

I'm using the following code to place it in the navigation bar:

```
self.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchController;
self.navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = NO;
```

[image: searchbar]

Inspecting the Interface shows the following hierarchy:
[image: hierarchy]

_UIBarBackground contained within the _UINavigationControllerManagedSearchPalette remains white.

Is there something I've missed when creating the UINavigationController?

Comment: have you try to set clearColor to your search bar ?

Comment: @CodeChanger that made no difference. The background is set on the _UIBarBackground, so changing the background on the UISearchBar will not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply background color same as the navigationBar tint color.

```
searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
searchBar.clearBackgroundColor()
```

Remove color of the searchBar by this way:

```
extension UISearchBar {

    func clearBackgroundColor() {
        guard let UISearchBarBackground: AnyClass = NSClassFromString("UISearchBarBackground") else { return }

        for view in self.subviews {
            for subview in view.subviews {
                if subview.isKind(of: UISearchBarBackground) {
                    subview.alpha = 0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with above code I am able to achieve this output

[image]

Hope this help.

Comment: Unfortunately that leaves a part of the navigation bar white when the searchbar is focused: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpSZ1.png. The searchbar's frame doesn't extend to the top of the view.

Comment: @DanielAndersson I have updated my answer please check it.

Comment: Tried this but got the same result as in my screenshot. The background is set on the search bar, but when the search bar is focused the navigation bar slides out of view revealing the UIBarBackground for the container view. 
I was able to fix the issue by placing a custom UIView below the UISearchBar with it's frame extending all the way to the top. A bit hacky but it works.

Comment: @DanielAndersson For me the search bar's background don't extend to top when it's focused anyway. So I added a custom bar background view to search results view that goes from `view.topAnchor` to `view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor`, and it works well.